# Share cache among the projects in one solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I have an solution with 4 projects and I need to share cache among the 4 projects. is it possible in .net?

In projet A

```
   public static CacheManagerClass{

    public static T GetCache<T>(string key) where T : class
    {
     object cachedObject = HttpRuntime.Cache.Get(key);
    return cachedObject ;
    }
    }
```

this is a sample of method i used to retrieve the cache object.
and the cache is created by an MVC application.I need to access the same cache using a wcf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand correctly, you are trying to reference the cache class from 3 (or 4) different executables. This cannot be done because each process loads it own instance of the cache class from the DLL.

You probably need to create some cache service (using WCF for example) which runs on another process (or on one of the existing processes) in order to manage caching for the multiple processes.

Answer (score 0):

Create the cache in the project referenced by other 3 projects and just use it?

Comment: I have added a reference to projects,but when other projects calling to that.the cache is always null

Comment: @ShanikaNishani, you need to paste some example code where you create and the code where you access the cache.